# How to turn spacy doc into nested list of tokens

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, nlp, spacy

Im using spacy and stanfordnlp for dependency parsing and i got a spacy doc. How could i turn that doc into nested list, where each sublist consists of children tokens of head

Comment: Please add input and expected output

Comment: give an example of a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a general solution to what you're asking, although including input, expected output, and sample code would help ensure that this answer is relevant. Explanation provided in comments.

```
import spacy

# Load relevant language/pipeline: here, the built-in small English web-based
# model.
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Run text through pipeline to create annotated doc.
sample_text = "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously."
doc = nlp(sample_text)

# Iterate through each token (t) in the doc object, and create a nested list
# of the children of each token. Keep in mind that like many spaCy attributes,
# token.children returns a generator. To access all of its elements at once,
# you will have to convert this generator into an object of type list.
child_list = [list(t.children) for t in doc]

# Now as an exercise, print out each token and check to see if you get the
# children you expected. Normally you would want to iterate on the objects 
# themselves -- we only use range() here for purposes of illustration.
for i in range(len(doc)):
    print("  token {}: {}".format(i + 1, doc[i]))
    print("    children: {}\n".format(child_list[i]))
```

As requested in the question, the output is a list of lists of child tokens. Note that while your terminal will display each token as it would text, these tokens are not simply text; they are spaCy `token` objects, each loaded with linguistic information based on the annotations in `doc`. The output will look as follows.

```
$ python example.py
  token 1: Colorless
    children: []
  token 2: green
    children: []
  token 3: ideas
    children: [Colorless, green]
  token 4: sleep
    children: [ideas, furiously, .]
  token 5: furiously
    children: []
  token 6: .
    children: []
```

And this is just what we'd expect:

[image: spaCy dependency parse of "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously."]

Answer (score 0):

here is example :

```
class Sent2Struct(object):

    def root(self,doc):
        for word in doc :
            if word.dep_ == 'ROOT' : return word

    def lol(self,root) :
        if len(list(root.children)) == 0 : return root.text
        childs = [ self.lol(child) for child in root.children ]
        return [root.text] + childs 



   In [100]: print( ss.lol(ss.root(nlp('the box is on the table'))) )                                                                                                           
   ['is', ['box', 'the'], ['on', ['table', 'the']]]
```

i.e.

```
   is(box(the), on(table(the)) )
```